# Publish a .NET Core Console application with right transformation settings

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm quite new to .NET Core application, and I was wondering if there's a simple way to deploy the right application.json based on the profile.
In .NET Standard application it was quite simple since we have web.config transformation/[Slowcheeta](https://github.com/Microsoft/slow-cheetah) but It doesn't seems to work with .NET Core Console app.

I've also read online that with ASP.NET Core application, we can use

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
.SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true) <--this
.AddEnvironmentVariables();
Configuration = builder.Build();
```

But on .NET Console app I don't have an `env.EnvironmentName`

I've also read that someone uses a `#IF-#ENDIF` statement to switch but this requires to put hands on code if a new publish profile is created

Any suggestion_

Comment: You can use the exact same code in console applications. The Microsoft.Extensions.* packages like configuration, dependency injection, logging aren't specific to one environment. I use them for a lot of command line tools

Comment: BTW in .NET Standard you **don't** have transformations. `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` is a .NET Standard library. Transformatinos were part of the Full .NET framework only, dropped because they were *too complex*. Instead of transformations with all their quirks (ever found a transformation resulted in an invalid config file?), you can *override* config values. Instead of transforming anything you just specify a *new* value for the setting you want to override and the last setting wins

Comment: For example, you can define a connection setting in `apssetings.json` or `myConfigFile.json` and then define a *new* value for the same setting in `myConfigFile.Production.json`. If you load the `Release` file after the original one, the new value wins

Comment: In past, I came across invalid config file, due to transformation, but in this way wouldn't strict information (for example dev DB password, dev configuration settings)  deployed as well as target machine configuration?

Comment: no,it's even safer that the old app.config file. You can use the [user secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=windows) tool to store secrets *outside* the repository during development. In production you can specify that the secrets will be loaded from a different provider, even Azure Key Vault or a similar secure storage service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To improve on the answer I have upvoted by @MarkusDresch, I wonder if OP says this did not work still because they do not have something setting up the correct environment. You need to have this being set correctly such as from an env variable of hostsetting.json:

```
            var host = new HostBuilder()
                   .ConfigureHostConfiguration(builder =>
                   {
                       builder.AddJsonFile("hostsettings.json", optional: true);
                   })
                   .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, builder) =>
                   {
                       builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
                       builder.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
                   })
```

With this example the hostsettings.json would have something like:

```
{
  "environment": "Development",
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json/)

The equivalent code would look something like this:

```
var builder = new HostBuilder();

builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((ctx, b) => b
  .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{ctx.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json"));
```

As far as i know this is only available for .NET Core 2.1. HostBuilder works pretty similar to ASP.NET WebHostBuilder and is available in NuGet package Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.

Comment: It doesn't resolves me ```HostBuilder```, in what assembly it's defined?Thanks

Comment: It's defined in Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.

Comment: Thanks, but this gives me the same situation like I've in the post of @dawid

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. ctx would be of type HostBuilderContext.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do it like that:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", true, true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", true, true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();   
}
```

Please remember about adding `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` nuget package.
There is also a way to get `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` like this:

```
new ConfigurationBuilder().AddEnvironmentVariables()
```

and finding that setting there.

And of course, you need to copy those configs to the output folder so that why will be accessible.

Comment: even if it's a consoleApp?

Comment: Yes, it's just a matter of proper Nuges. If you don't have any please add: Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json, Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions, Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables.

Comment: Excuse me but I'm in a CONSOLE app, not ASP.net.... it doesnt' resolve the ```ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT``` and it makes sense...

Comment: @advapi all of the extensions work on any application. You *can* define that environment variable on any machine and it works just fine. You can use any environment variable name you want, it's just a string! Using `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is a common convention though.

Comment: so I would have to define on the server an environment variable... and so the publish will contain all the configurations, am I right?

Comment: @advapi no. You don't *have* to - the first `true` is for the `optional` parameter. You could deploy the "release" file only on the production server if you wanted. It's a common convention though - you can use separate setting files for staging, testing, QA, release environments.

Comment: @asvapi I'd sugggest you read [Essential.NET - Configuration in .NET Core](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt632279.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in MSDN Magazine. It explains how configuration works

Comment: I've read it... but still unable to overcome my difficulties.you told the enviormentName can be a string, but this mean that on QA/Stage/Prod enviorment I've to set a variable for a property that can be ```ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT``` or anything else

Comment: You can call it NETCORE_ENVIRONMENT without ASP and set it anywhere you want (batch script that launches your app, global env variable etc.)

Comment: Where is ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT defined? In my console app is returns null. How is this varied between deployment environemnts?

Comment: This is an environment variable but can be also configured on VS on project properties.

Answer (score 1):

You do have access to Environment. That should be enough:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
.SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}.json", optional: true)
.AddEnvironmentVariables();
Configuration = builder.Build();
```